# c0000005 exception in ext. analyze debugger extension

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, xdebug

I am starting the service of our companies product and w3wp.exe crashes at the same time. 
I have a system crash dump. When I try to analyze it in Windbg, I get the following error:

```
c0000005 Exception in ext.analyze debugger extension.
  PC: 00000000`08867875  VA: 00000000`00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000`00000000
```

Comment: You need to give more information, as to what you were doing and symptoms, etc. Hope this [helps](http://www.andreybazhan.com/windbg-access-violation-exception-0xc0000005-when-running-the-for_each_module-command.html)

Comment: It looks like you want to run `!analyze`. What kind of dump do you have? Kernel/User, 32/64, small/full? You tagged this C, but isn't XDebug for PHP? There are too many open questions at the moment. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @MilindDeore Thomas, Pardon me for my ignorance. I am doing this 'Debugging' thing for the very first time using 'WinDbg'. I am still learning it to use effectively. However, I cant tell you its details like Kernel/User, 32/64, small/full as I don't know how to determine it. It would be very helpful if you elaborate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Thomas it is a crash in windbg ext debugger extension and probably doesnt have anything to do with dump details   @ op get an older version of windbg (iirc the newest or the insider preview version of windbg does not run correctly and spits out various errors including dependency errors if you run them in windows 7) so try an older version of windbg

Comment: which windbg.exe version do you use?

Comment: @blabb Yeah you were correct. I was able to resolve this issue. Can you please post the answer in answer section so that I can accept it officially. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an access violation error in ext debugger extension

if you are running a latest version of windbg  try downloading an older version of windbg

that should solve the issue

the latest windbg version as well as insider preview versions do not run correctly in os like windows 7 and spit out various errors including dependency erors

these versions of windbg are probably tested only on the bleeding edge of the day like windows rs3 redstone wtc  and aren't backward compatible

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17061.1000 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: calc
The call to LoadLibrary(ext) failed, Win32 error 0n127  <<<<<<<<<<<< 
    "The specified procedure could not be found."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
```

Comment: ms will fix the win7/8 compatibility in next insider SDK. This was an unwanted regression.